# Firemonkey (Delphi) TListbox with MultiSelect getting selected items

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.2-tokyo, tlistbox

I'm using Firemonkey in Delphi 10.2 Tokyo.

I have an HD Form with a `TListBox` with its `MultiSelectStyle` set to either `Extended` or `Default`.

I am able to select multiple items, however I can't find a way to programmatically determine which items are selected.

This code

```
for loop := 0 to Listbox1.Count - 1 do
if Listbox1.Selected[loop] then ; //Do Something
```

that I've seen variations of ***does not compile***:

> [dcc32 Error] MainApplication.pas(60): E2149 Class does not have a default property

I've been through the various properties and methods of `TListBox` and I can't see a way of finding out which items are selected.

Can anyone please lend me a hand on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In FireMonkey, the [`TListBox.Selected`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.ListBox.TCustomListBox.Selected) property is a pointer to the first selected [`TListBoxItem`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/FMX.ListBox.TListBoxItem) object.  It is NOT an array of boolean states like [it is in VCL](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TCustomListBox.Selected).  You must have been looking at VCL examples, not FMX examples.

The error message is because you are trying to apply your `[loop]` index to a specific `TListBoxItem` object, which does not have a `default` property.

Use this instead:

```
for loop := 0 to ListBox1.Count - 1 do
begin
  if ListBox1.ListItems[loop].IsSelected then
    ...
end;
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for!